# Alternative term for 'smoke test'

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language

I currently work as a Test Engineer. I test (power) electronics.

One test I often perform is something called a ["smoke test"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(electrical)). Among engineers, this is a common term:

> "The phrase smoke test comes from electronic hardware testing. You plug in a new board and turn on the power. If you see smoke coming from the board, turn off the power. You don't have to do any more testing."

Easy to understand, right? But not necessarily professional in a test report. One of my colleagues, the one having to deal with the customers, notified me we should probably change the wording in reports. He's afraid it will be considered pejorative. I don't necessarily agree with him, but sure, let's find an alternative. Except I can't think of an alternative to "smoke test" that's equally unambiguous and clear.

What would be a proper equivalent term for "smoke test"?

Target audience is engineers, salesmen and managers when addressed in written reports.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61815/discussion-on-question-by-mast-alternative-term-for-smoke-test).

Comment: This could be really simple as "PIT" for Plug In Test.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> ## Critical Power-On Failure Test
>
> The system or component tested failed to meet basic power-on requirements, and was unable to be safely activated. No further tests were performed.

Being the son of a member of the USAF, working in an area where electronic systems were *frequently* tested for this, the best term and phrasing I can think of is the aforementioned. Basically, instead of calling it by the *physical*-result, you refer to the technical result.

We use the modifier `Critical` to indicate that it is a significant failure. The test itself *is* a power-on test, `POST`, whatever you want to call it. Essentially, we just refer to the idea that power-on failed, and it was a critical failure. This is also a *safety* test more than anything: you don't continue testing because it's *unsafe* to test something smoking.

You could also consider the modifier `Basic`, to indicate that the test *truly* does not expect much other than a simplistic ability to power the device on *without* shorting it, catching it on fire, or electrocuting yourself.

Comment: +1 especially for POST. Pointy-haired managers love acronyms.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Thinking about it now, I am *technically* wrong about `POST`, because most smoke-tests are not even with the device in the "on" state, but just plugging it in and hoping you don't get zapped, though POST is the most *relevant* acronym I can think of. :)

Comment: Well, POST is commonly meant to mean Power-On Self-Test. That's the basic test a computer for example performs / performed before trying to hand control over to the bootloader. Now leaving out the S for self would result in POT, and I don't know if calling it POT evokes quite the right image...

Comment: @Deduplicator to confuse things further, POTS was the Plain Old Telephone System - so I read POT in context as Plain Old Telephone.

Answer (score 6):

**Shakedown Test**

> [(MW)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shakedown): a test under operating conditions of something new [...] for possible faults and defects

Comment: "Operating conditions" means a more involved test than just "does it catch fire when we turn it on?" though.

Comment: Idiomatically, "Smoke Test" and "Shakedown Test" are synonymous, with "Shakedown" sounding less drastic or catastrophic. If the OP is explicitly talking about a test wherein the pass/fail criteria is "did it catch fire?" (which is not evident based on the wording of the question) then the only applicable phrase would be "Smoke Test'. If, however, it is more of a simple test to check for faults or defects under general operating conditions, I think the answer holds water.

Comment: Hm, it sounded to me like the OP is talking about a test under less than operating conditions. I'll ask.

Answer (score 4):

For something more complicated, like a factory or a power plant, initial tests like these are referred to [startup and commissioning tests](http://www.technicaldiagnostic.com/tdstsu/start-up-commissioning/).

It seems like *smoke test* is a *start-up test* - you start the device, observe it for any obvious problems, and shut it down.

I believe **start-up test** is equally unambiguous and clear - it can be reasonably implied that the reason for the *start-up test* is to look for any obvious problems.

Comment: "start-up test" could also apply to testing that output (and internal) voltage levels stabilize where they should during/after an inrush of current when powered on.  But a "smoke test" doesn't imply anything about checking for correction functioning, just absence of catastrophic failure / blowing a fuse.  A power supply that keeps its output at 0 volts could pass a smoke test but fail any other kind of start-up test.  So **it's unfortunately more ambiguous than smoke test**.  For something with an embedded CPU, a "start-up test" would probably include having that boot up.

Comment: @Peter Cordes as used this term covers a broad number of tests that include inspection, limited testing (such as confirming that each motor correctly responds to each control center icon), and, yes, actually starting.  Some examples [here](http://www.amg-eng.com/services/alacarte/commissioning-start-up.php).  So the term includes any test in this group, some which *may* start the plant and many which don't.  I understand a smoke test *may* involve starting something or may not.  There doesn't seem to be more ambiguity in one term than the other.

Comment: @Peter Cordes your specific example was *a power supply that keeps its output at 0 volts* - there are many startup tests that power supply would pass, so you are not correct when you say *but fail any other kind of start-up test*.  It obviously wouldn't pass a test of actually starting, but there are probably some smoke tests that it wouldn't pass either.  It just depends what is involved in a smoke test.  If it's, say, a coffee pot and you plug it in and see if it works without any obvious problems then that's a smoke test it fails if the power supply keeps its output at 0 volts.

Comment: The OP made it pretty clear that they were using "smoke test" to mean "plug it in and look for smoke" (and if so, no further testing is possible).  You're talking about looking for smoke during testing of features / functionality, it seems.  edit: seems you're using "smoke test" metaphorically.  The OP is talking about literal smoke (or sparks or fuse-blowing), and excluding other kinds of basic testing from the definition.

Comment: @Peter Cordes nevertheless no matter how they use the term internally it has a broadly recognized meaning.  He also said it was meant to be interpreted by non-technical people like salesmen, so they would only know the general meaning of the word, not how he used it.  **If they knew how he used it, there would be no need to find a different term at all.**  Therefore, my comparison is between the general meaning of *smoke test* and the general meaning of *startup test*.  Your desire to limit the meaning to his internal use is nonsensical since he's already said that's not how it's perceived.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants a term that has the narrow meaning described so their engineers will still know what they're talking about, but that won't scare sales people when they see it.  Thus saving the engineers from having to translate into marketing-speak but without introducing any ambiguity into their communications with each other.  (I also disagree that a hardware "smoke test" usually understood as more general than looking for literal smoke, but maybe I'm wrong about that; I'm not really a hardware guy.  Not really relevant since the OP is looking for the narrow meaning.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes if they are going to use a term internally then the engineers using that term internally should know what they mean by that term.  They are already taking a more narrow meaning of *smoke test* than its general meaning, as you pointed out.  So they can do the same with *startup test*.  For that matter they can call it *blue test* and it will be understood internally.  The need for a different term was pointed out by a *colleague* who was primarily concerned about *how customers would interpret the term they use*.

Comment: re: meaning of "smoke test": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(electrical) defines it narrowly, the way the OP does.  But you're claiming that's not a correct definition?

Comment: @Peter Cordes the souce you cite says **In Lessons Learned in Software Testing, Cem Kaner, James Bach, and Brett Pettichord provided the origin of the term: "The phrase smoke test comes from electronic hardware testing. You plug in a new board and turn on the power. If you see smoke coming from the board, turn off the power. You don't have to do any more testing."**  So you do a **startup test** for that piece of harware and look for problems.  **The general meaning of *smoke test* and general meaning of *startup test* are THE SAME per YOUR SOURCE.**

Comment: "blue test" or some other code-name is closer to fitting the OP's requirements.  A term that they can put in reports that will be read by other engineers *and* by sales people, and that isn't "smoke test".  Presumably they still want to be able to use the term "startup test" for other kinds of startup tests.

Comment: You quoted the one part of that article that's about software, not hardware.  The OP *is* talking about hardware, where it's not a general term.

Comment: @Peter Cordes your own sources are contradicting your arguments.  As you mentioned, you aren't any kind of technical expert.  I suggest you just leave it to people who are more technical than you are.  If they have a problem, let them speak up.  Or take your comments to chat.  You're just repeating yourself now.  As I already pointed out **The need for a different term was pointed out by a colleague who was primarily concerned about how customers would interpret the term they use.**

Comment: I was talking about the "Smoke testing in electronics and electrical engineering" section of that article, which you are purposely ignoring to focus on the one part of the article that mentions the use of the term in a field other than testing electrical components.  I've built electronics as a hobby, but it's been a few years.

Comment: @Peter Cordes if you would **actually read** what I have been saying ***I think I have been pretty clear that I am referring to the general definition of smoke test**.  I am concerned about **the definition that customers and non-technical people will understand because that's the reason they are looking for a new term**.  Now please please please **take your comments to chat you aren't saying anything new just repeating yourself.**

Answer (score -3):

**Sanity Test**

> Software sanity tests are synonymous with smoke tests.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check

Comment: OP isn't testing software - and in the hardware world a sanity check is *very* different.

Comment: Can you say more about what sanity check implies in hardware? My answer does not mean to say that software and hardware are the same, but that sanity testing is an alternative term in a closely related field and may be suitable outside of software testing.

Comment: That wikipedia article should really put this part sooner: "*Another, possibly more common usage of 'sanity test' is to denote checks which are performed within program code* (e.g. `assert()`).  A build sanity test is a smoke test, but "sanity test" without that qualifier isn't that specific.

Comment: See also MikeJRamsey56's better definition of software smoke tests [in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397856/alternative-term-for-smoke-test#comment945032_397856): short tests of a new build to check that the build succeeded.  Wikipedia is claiming this is what "sanity test" means in software terminology, but most people would not agree.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've only ever used 'sanity test' in the software world to indicate that it passes all *basic* UX requirements, like the 'Add' button is actually 'Add' and not 'Delete', for example. Never really to test functionality, just to test that things are *mostly* sensical.

Comment: @EBrown: hmm, now that you mention it, "sanity check" and "sanity test" may have different meanings in software.  A "sanity check" is something like an `assert()`, but like you I don't think I'd call that a "sanity test".